# Network (offline) install of Windows XP SP1

Tags: windows-xp, service-pack

I am installing Windows XP Pro on a virtual machine (Virtual Box).  The install went fine, and networking appears to be fine (can browse the internet through IE).  However, I am unable to install Windows XP SP1a.

I downloaded the SP1a express installer, which is a small couple MB installer that downloads the remaining content during installation.  However, when I run the installer, I get "server did not respond" errors.

Does anyone know of an official place to get the offline network installation version of SP1 or SP1a?  I can't seem to find it on the MS website anywhere, everything I find points to the 'express' installer.

Comment: Why SP1a and not SP3?

Comment: @grawity don't you have to install sp1 first? then sp2, before sp3?

Comment: No. SP2 then SP3 is enough.

Comment: or just SP3 i believe, any SP will include the SP before it

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Just tried SP3 first - complained that the OS must be at least SP1 to proceed.

Comment: @Journeyman: XP SP2 is cumulative (includes all of SP1), SP3 is partly incremental (includes SP2 but not SP1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From what I can find, Windows XP Service Pack 1 *did not have* an offline install version.

However, SP2 includes all updates released before, so SP1 is not necessary. It should be enough to install SP2, followed by SP3. This doesn't include updates *after* SP3, though, so be sure to visit Windows Update.

You can download [Service Pack 2](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28) and [Service Pack 3](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24) from the [Service Pack Center](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/service-packs).

Correction provided by iOSXPC: [Service Pack 1a](http://www.download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3-19990518/cabpool/xpsp1a_8441053935adbfc760b966e5e413d3415a753213.exe) does have an official 125 MB offline installation.

Comment: Yes they did ,I still have copies of the original offline installers, XP SP1 and the later SP1a, 137mb and 128mb respectively.

Comment: My bet is that since SP1 is no longer supported, you can't download it as an offline from the usual spots.  Notice you can't download 2K anymore. . .

Comment: Current (2021) download links: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=xp+service+pack and sort by size.