# Update Windows XP to SP3 without internet

Tags: windows-xp, updates, sp3

I've been asked to update some computers running Windows XP (without any service packs) to Windows XP SP3. The computers don't have an internet connection (only a small intranet) and have never been updated since first install.

Do I need to install SP1a first, then SP2, then SP3, or can I install SP3 immediately?

And where do I find the right files, that don't require an internet connection during installation?

Comment: 1) I recently answered a question from someone who needed to install SP2 before he could install SP3. I **guess** you need all three of them. 2) Check out http://download.wsusoffline.net/ for offline updating.  3) I hope USB ports and CDROM drives are disabled on those systems, or at the very last that the antivirus software is regularly updated. If not add that to the TODO-list

Comment: Thanks. I have downloaded the service packs and also the WSUS software. I'll try the WSUS one first. I compiled the package and put it on an usb-drive. If it doesn't work for some reason, I'll still have the service packs. Your third point is exactly why these systems need to be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are links to offline installation files for SP1a, SP2 and SP3. Download them on system with an internet connection and use them to update any systems with no internet connection.

- [Windows XP SP1a](http://www.download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3-19990518/cabpool/xpsp1a_8441053935adbfc760b966e5e413d3415a753213.exe) (SP1 was later superseded by SP1a)
- [Widows XP SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28)
- [Windows XP SP3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24)

If you want to create only single installation disk of all the previous updates including SP3, go to [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25129) to download an ISO image.

Also, you can refer [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/347245/network-offline-install-of-windows-xp-sp1).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'll burn the ISO onto a CD and will have the separate packs with me on a usb-drive when I go there. (As well as the WSUS package @Hennes mentioned.)

Comment: Except for the SP1a, the rest of the links as of today are broken.

Answer (score 0):

You might also make a slipstream install CD, which has SP3 integrated into the install CD. Of course, it is only helpful if you can install from scratch, and not upgrade existing systems where you need to retain installed programs and settings.

Here's a guide:
http://winsupersite.com/article/windows-xp2/slipstreaming-windows-xp-with-service-pack-3-sp3-128464